# C++ What's the named cast equivalent

Tags: c++, casting

What's the named cast equivalent for the following old-style cast?

```
const string *ps;
void *pv;

pv = (void*)ps; // <--- this
```

Is it `pv = static_cast<void*>(const_cast<string*>(ps));` ?

Comment: Yes. Now wait for that one smart ass who answers with just a single 'yes'. Or the guy who rearranges it as `const_cast<void*>(static_cast<const void*>(ps))`. EDIT: I claim hipsterdom to this behavior.

Comment: I think `pv = const_cast<string *>(ps);` is enough.

Comment: Why don't you ask your compiler ?

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, the `string*` to `void*` cast is implicit so one only needs to get rid of the `const`.

Comment: Or that one dude who throws in an implicit cast. :-P

@AliBurakKulakli last I checked reinterpret_cast can't handle CV-qualifiers.

Comment: @AliBurakKulakli `reinterpret_cast` is almost never appropriate, and it 1. would be an overkill in this case too, 2. it doesn't work IIRC.

Comment: @syam There's no such thing as an 'implicit cast'. Casts are, by definition, explicit. There is an implicit type conversion, though.

Comment: @Atash The comment above applies to you too, there is no 'implicit cast', only an implicit type conversion. Casting is an explicit type conversion.

Comment: @H2CO3 Right, my bad, I meant implicit conversion of course.

Comment: That's correct. reinterpret_cast is not appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
pv = const_cast<string *>(ps);
```

is good enough - `void *` is implicitly assignable **from** any (non-qualified) data (object) pointer type.

(Of course, for the same reason, a direct assignment to `const void *` **without any casting** would work.)

Comment: "void * is implicitly assignable from any data (object) pointer type" then why not use `pv = ps` directly?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Because `void *` is not `const`-qualified. Direct assignment to a `const void *` would work. Did you try it? If not, I suggest you to do so, I just tries it and everything works as I described here.

Comment: I know, but you said "void * is implicitly assignable from any data (object) pointer type" which implies otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to understand what was happening.

Comment: @H2CO3 I do feel satisfied. AAAAHHHHHHH! (which is why I was the first upvote after the edit)